# Multiple replace characters in array

Tags: php, regex

I have:

```
$content = file_get_contents('data.html');
preg_match_all('/<span class="ng-binding">.*?<\/span>/is', $content, $matches);
print_r(array_values(array_unique($matches[0])));

Array
(
    [0] => 3 January 2018 - Month - Month of Circumstances
    [1] => 2 February 2018 - Month - A New Advancement
    [2] => 1 March 2018 - Month - The Threat
    [3] => 31 April 2018 - Month - Month of Prediction 
    [4] => 30 May 2018 - Month - Seven Days
)
```

How can I remove and replace characters so the end array would be something like...

```
Content.2017.S01E01.Month.of.Circumstances.HOTSTAR.mp4
Content.2017.S01E01.A.New.Advancement.HOTSTAR.mp4
Content.2017.S01E01.The.Threat.HOTSTAR.mp4
Content.2017.S01E01.Month.of.Prediction.HOTSTAR.mp4 
Content.2017.S01E01.Seven.Days.HOTSTAR.mp4
```

Comment: All characters before the last `-` will be replaced with that.

Comment: I've tried some regex but still not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either do 2 `preg_replace` calls or use `preg_replace_callback` and `preg_replace`. A regex such as `.*-\s*(.*)` will give everything until the last `-` then `\s*` will allow any additional whitespace characters. Then you have the part you care about in the first capture group. With that capture group you then can replace all non alphanumerical characters.

```
$array = array('3 January 2018 - Month - Month of Circumstances',
                '2 February 2018 - Month - A New Advancement', 
                '1 March 2018 - Month - The Threat',
                '31 April 2018 - Month - Month of Prediction',
                '30 May 2018 - Month - Seven Days');
foreach($array as $item) {
    echo preg_replace_callback('/.*-\s*(.*)/', function($match){
        return 'Content.2017.S01E01.' . preg_replace('/\W+/', '.', $match[1]) . '.HOTSTAR.mp4';
    }, $item) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Note `\w` includes underscores so if that is a special character you also want replaced use a character class including the underscore in place of the `\W`. This should do it `[\W_]` (with the quantifier).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `preg_replace` with array values for `pattern` and `replacement`. Patterns are replaced in the order of the elements in the array. So the first replace in this code replaces spaces with a `.` and the second replace adds the leading and trailing text to the extracted name.

```
$array = array('3 January 2018 - Month - Month of Circumstances',
                '2 February 2018 - Month - A New Advancement', 
                '1 March 2018 - Month - The Threat',
                '31 April 2018 - Month - Month of Prediction',
                '30 May 2018 - Month - Seven Days');
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $line) {
    $new_array[] = preg_replace(array('/\s+/', '/^.*?-([\w.]+)$/'),
                                array('.', 'Content.2017.S01E01$1.HOTSTAR.mp4'),
                                $line);
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Content.2017.S01E01.Month.of.Circumstances.HOTSTAR.mp4
    [1] => Content.2017.S01E01.A.New.Advancement.HOTSTAR.mp4
    [2] => Content.2017.S01E01.The.Threat.HOTSTAR.mp4
    [3] => Content.2017.S01E01.Month.of.Prediction.HOTSTAR.mp4
    [4] => Content.2017.S01E01.Seven.Days.HOTSTAR.mp4
)
```

Comment: I'm curious. Why did you change your mind about accepting this answer?